# How to get records if only all of the list elements included in nested collections?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I want to filter my query using MongoDb c# driver. I have a query list so I need to filter records if all the list item included in the sub collection of a collection.

```
public class Hotels
    {
        [BsonId]
        // standard BSonId generated by MongoDb
        public ObjectId InternalId { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<int> Amenities { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a query parameter "amenities" as string then splitted with respect to ",".

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(amenties))
    {
        var amenityList =Array.ConvertAll<string,int>( amenties.Split(","),int.Parse).ToList();

        filter &= Builders<Hotels>.Filter.Where(r => r.Amenities.All(i => amenityList.Contains(i)));
    }

var result =_context.GetCollection<Hotels>(typeof(Hotels).Name).Find(filter);
```

Throws exception : unsupported filter. Thus, how can I fix this query ?
Thanks

Comment: AminityList contains duplicate records?

Comment: All of them unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Where` expression is wrong. have a look at the last line of the following code for the correct expression.

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Hotel : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int[] Amenities { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            (new[] {
                new Hotel{ Name= "hotel one", Amenities = new[] {1, 3, 5, 7 } },
                new Hotel{ Name= "hotel two", Amenities = new[] {2, 4, 6, 8 } }
            }).Save();

            string amenities = "2,4,6,8";
            int[] amenityList = amenities.Split(",").Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a)).ToArray();

            var result = DB.Find<Hotel>()
                           .Many(h => amenityList.All(a => h.Amenities.Contains(a)));
        }
    }
}
```

it generates the following find query:

```java
"command": {
    "find": "Hotel",
    "filter": {
        "Amneties": {
            "$all": [
                NumberInt("2"),
                NumberInt("4"),
                NumberInt("6"),
                NumberInt("8")
            ]
        }
    }
}
```